# Parsing JSON data through html pages

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, variables

I get a string with JSON format and I want to send it to profile .html
my problem is how to save the string and parse it with the variable that i fetch from the JSON , to the profile.html page because I need session and user_id variables from page to page.
when i debug, the debuger says that the 'user_id' in not defined;
thank's a lot

```
enter code here

   gloabl variables are User_id,Session;
    var params ={
    username: document.getElementById('usernameId').value, 
    password: document.getElementById('passwordId').value,
    rememberMe :document.getElementById('rememberId').value,
    };

login(params, function(data){
                        var account=JSON.stringify(data);
                        account=JSON.parse(account);
                        if(account.success==true){
                             User_id=account.user_id;
                            session=account.session;
                            window.location='profile.html';

                        }
enter code here
```

Comment: can you please show you json string...

Comment: {"user_id":"123456","session":"abcdefg"}

Answer (score 0):

Code with edition:

```
login(params, function(data)
{
  var account=JSON.parse(data); // this serve the purpose                    
  if(account.success==true){
    var value= account.user_id + ', ' + account.session; 
    // now you can either pass it as query string or as parameter to your destination page.
    window.location='profile.html';
}
```

Have you defined the User_id and session as variables?

Comment: if(account.success==true){
save(account.user_id,account.session);
window.location='profile.html';
.......
var User_id;
var Session;
function save(u,s){
User_id=u;
Session=s;
}
but still debugger says: User_id and Session are undefined

Comment: Are you having data in account.user_id and session. Check with some static values.
Please try once. Apart from that, I don't see any issue in code. 
Try to share the whole declaration if possible, will check once.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not set in account.user_id. Please check Json. Enter some static data and check it first. Then check json .

Comment: with static data it works properly. but i want to get data dynamiclly.

Comment: Then it's clearly issue with JSON Data.You can check it through browser console.log You need to set user_id in account object. Please set it. It will automatically work. If you need any help then share the code. Check data in login. You can use alert(data.toSource()) to check it's property. I need to check the variable and their values in data. Please let me know will it able to help you or not?